# Unable to copy file "obj\Debug\Some.dll" to "bin\Debug\Some.dll".... because it is being used by another process"

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, build, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

Is anyone else facing this issue in VS 2017? This only happens in VS 2017 for all Xamarin Forms based projects irrespective of the nuget versions of Xamarin Forms.

The same projects open & work fine in VS 2015.

Any clues on what could be wrong?

I am using VS 2017 Enterprise edition Version 15.2 (26430.6) release.

Comment: The only way I can make my project work is by deleting the bin folder in my PCL. Which is a major productivity drain as at times you forget deleting them, it takes time compiling & you get the same error again

Comment: it is a standard crappy anti-malware problem.  Disable it and try again, find another one.

Comment: If by anti malware you mean the Anti Virus, I am only using Windows Defender. But then it doesn't give me any problems on VS 2015 either

Answer (score 0):

Just update your Visual Studio and the problem should vanish. Its a known bug that got fixed later. I had the same issue and it was gone after the update.